# MySQL: ORDER BY with RANGE query, bad performance

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-order-by, where-in

i'm working on a query that should select last 20 posts sent by a defined list of users from a *MyIsam* table containing more than *400,000 records*. The only problem is that query runs in about **0.6sec** and sometimes more than 2 seconds.

```
SELECT post_id
FROM posts
WHERE post_author IN (32, 85, 222, 81, 250,  [..cut..] , 5908, 4930, 6658, 6757, 6398, 6324, 6629)
ORDER BY post_id DESC
LIMIT 20
```

If i remove *ORDER BY* query is much faster, and it uses the correct index on "post_author" column, instead it performs a full table scan... What's the best way to make a query like this?

---

### Test #1 with author_index

- **PRIMARY** (post_id)
- **author_index** (post_author)

Time: **0.7s**
[image: Explain with many authors]

```
SELECT post_id
FROM posts
WHERE post_author IN (32, 85, 222, 81, 250,  [..cut..] , 5908, 4930, 6658, 6757, 6398, 6324, 6629)
ORDER BY post_id DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Time: **0.004s**
[image: Explain with few authors]

```
SELECT post_id
FROM posts
WHERE post_author IN (58,68)
ORDER BY post_id DESC
LIMIT 20
```

---

### Test #2 with compound index

- **PRIMARY** (post_id)
- **view_posts_index** (post_id, post_author)

Time: **0.05s**
[image: Explain with many authors]

```
SELECT post_id
FROM posts
WHERE post_author IN (32, 85, 222, 81, 250,  [..cut..] , 5908, 4930, 6658, 6757, 6398, 6324, 6629)
ORDER BY post_id DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Time: **1.5s**
[image: Explain with few authors]

```
SELECT post_id
FROM posts
WHERE post_author IN (58,68)
ORDER BY post_id DESC
LIMIT 20
```

---

### Test #3 with compound index and author_index

- **PRIMARY** (post_id)
- **view_posts_index** (post_id, post_author)
- **author_index** (post_author)

Time: **0.7s**
[image: Explain with many authors]

```
SELECT post_id
FROM posts
WHERE post_author IN (32, 85, 222, 81, 250,  [..cut..] , 5908, 4930, 6658, 6757, 6398, 6324, 6629)
ORDER BY post_id DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Time: **0.0037s**
[image: Explain with few authors]

```
SELECT post_id
FROM posts
WHERE post_author IN (58,68)
ORDER BY post_id DESC
LIMIT 20
```

---

Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you any index on post_author?

Comment: Is your post_id column an index that table? If it isn't, it should be set up as a Primary Key.

Comment: Try creating the compound index `(post_author, post_id)`.

Comment: If the table is MyISAM, try the (reverse order) compound index: `(post_id, post_author)`

Comment: It looks there is no way to use a multiple index with a range condition and an order by... any solution? I have posted all the suggested indexes and relative queries :(

Answer (score 1):

Create an index on both the post_author and post_id columns:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_post_search ON posts(post_author, post_id);
```

This will allow MySQL to satisfy the entire query by only looking at this index.

Comment: Thanks, it takes **0.18/0.19 seconds** now. It's a good result XD, probably it can still be improved.

Comment: Can you post the result of an EXPLAIN?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your query uses an index on the `post_id` (and probably on `post_author`, but that's not part of your question), otherwise in your case a whole range scan will be started and stopped as soon as the required amount of rows are generated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would try that, ensuring to have one index on column author and naturally an index on the unique id too :)

```
SELECT p2.post_id FROM posts p2
WHERE p2.post_id IN (
  SELECT p1.post_id
  FROM posts p1
  WHERE p1.post_author IN (32, 85, 222, 81, 250,  [..cut..] , 5908, 4930, 6658, 6757, 6398, 6324, 6629)
 )
ORDER BY p2.post_id
LIMIT 20
```

Let me know if it solve your problem

Comment: Thanks, i've already tried this solution but it gets much slower, probably the subquery without limit contains too many records, too many ids to select.